Explicit Representative for Subregular Nilpotent Orbit in type $D$
Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 4}$ and consider the Lie algebra of type $D_n$
$$
\mathfrak{so}_{2n} = \left\{ X \in \text{Mat}_{2n \times 2n} \left( \mathbb{C} \right) \mid X = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & - A^\top \end{pmatrix} \text{ where }A, B, C \in \text{Mat}_{n \times n} \left( \mathbb{C} \right) \text{ with $B, C$ skew symmetric} \right\}. 
$$
As I understand, the nilpotent orbits of $\mathfrak{so}_{2n}$ correspond to partitions of $2n$ such that the even parts occur with even multiplicity, and there is some ambiguity for partitions with only even parts. Moreover, the regular nilpotent orbit corresponds to the parition $(2n - 1, 1)$ and the subregular one is $(2n - 3, 3)$.
My question is, what is an explicit representative for the subregular nilpotent orbit?
